# Confusion with my layouts - android

Tags: android, layout, resolution

I'm currently working on my application, which tries to support different screen resolutions but I noticed a major problem with my layouts. I'll explain:

I have two folders in my res folder. They are called "layout" and "layout-sw360dp" which is meant to support big screens like Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC One, etc.
Now, when I try to run my application on my private phone, galaxy S4, the app looks fine and all of the images and the components are perfect.

But when I try to run my app on an HTC One device, suddenly the layout looks small, like very small. It supposes to fit the entire screen, like in my galaxy s4.
It's like HTC One and Galaxy S4 don't use the same layout folder, although their screens sizes are almost the same.

If you guys can clarify this matter for me I would really appreaciate that.

Edit: I have tried to run my app on an Samsung Galaxy S5 device and it looks find, like the way it should. What is the problem with HTC One?

Comment: htc may have diffrent resolution look at the specification and compare

Comment: That's not correct. They both have 1080X1920 resolution.

Answer (score 0):

**Physical size** is usually measured in inches, it simply tells you the real device's screen size

dpi, is NOT correlated with it. Dpi expresses screen density, how many pixels are shown in a given area (usually a square inch). It could be considered as a measure of screen quality.

**Resolution** is given by the product of the two; it expresses the total number of physical pixels on a screen.

```
android:anyDensity="true"
```

Samsung Galaxy S4, HTC One have different physical size : [DIFFERENCE](http://www.phonearena.com/phones/compare/Samsung-Galaxy-S4,HTC-One/phones/7597,7678)

Refer this for how to choice best resolution : [DOC](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch)

Comment: OK I see the HTC One has slightly bigger ppi number than the Galaxy S4 but aren't they fall under the same layout/resource folder? I mean, the difference between them is not so big.

Comment: what have u used for drawable ? it should be **/layout-sw360dp/** and drawables in **/drawable-xhdpi/**

Comment: refere http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html

Comment: I saw on another post that HTC One and Galaxy S4 use drawable-xxhdpi. What is the correct folder to put resources in for these devices?

Comment: I tried to play a little bit with the drawables folder but it didn't solve the problem. Then I tried to run the app on Nexus 5 and Galaxy S5 devices and the app works fine. Everything looks fantastic. I just can't get it. What's the problem with HTC One? It suppose to work like the other devices.

Comment: Ok let me know if you discover new things.